# Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally, Process exited with error code 199

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Env:
node: 8.5.0; npm: 5.3.0;
protractor: 5.2.2; chromedriver: 2.35.528139, Google Chrome 63.0.3239.132
angular:

```
├── @0.0.28
├── @angular/cli@1.6.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.1.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.1.3
├── @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.1.3
├── @angular/forms@5.1.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@5.1.3
├── @angular/platform-browser@5.1.3
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.1.3
├── @angular/router@5.1.3
├── @angular/upgrade@5.1.3
```

os: linux 16.4,

protractor.config.js below

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/**/*.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  directConnect: true,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',

  framework: 'jasmine2',
  onPrepare: function() {
      var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
      // If we are running via circleci, then use the CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS output directory. 
      var outputDir = "test/test_out";
      if (process.env.CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS) {
        outputDir = process.env.CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS;
      }

      console.log("Logging Protractor JUnit output to " + outputDir);

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
          consolidateAll: true,
          savePath: outputDir,
          filePrefix: 'protractor-xmloutput'
      }));
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }

};
```

error here

```
[09:47:20] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.4.0-36-generic x86_64)
[09:47:20] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.4.0-36-generic x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts:90:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:187:39)
    at driverprovider_.setupEnv.then (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:279:27)
    at _fulfilled (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/var/lib/postgresql/carepilot-web/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[09:47:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I run command node_modules/.bin/protractor test/e2e/ui_test/protractor_conf_chrome/protractor.conf.js locally, it is ok, but it throw error when i run remote env; I run chromedrive and chrome manully, they are work, but chromdrive start chrome throw error.
What's the matter? Can any one give some suggestion? Many thanks!
[image]

Comment: The error message say `(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382` not as your mentioned `chromedriver: 2.35.528139`.  Please check the chromedrvier version is compatible with browser on your remote env.  If your local and remote are same browser version, try use same chromedriver version as local on remote.

Comment: @yong Thanks for you suggestion, my type error. I have tried, but it failed too. protractor: 5.2.2 => chromedriver: 2.35.528139, protractor: 5.0.0 => chromedriver: 2.26.436382. Both of the above don't work.

Comment: you can start chromdriver on remote env manually?  If so, please update question add the command to start chromedriver.  Did you give a try on other chromedriver version like 2.33, 2,34

Comment: Yes I can start it manually, but I didn't know how to start it by command,do you know? And the protractor specified the chromedriver v2.35.5 from v5.0.0 to 5.22, so I think I cannot use other version.

Comment: login on the remote env, cd the project folder, execute `node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.35.exe --port=4444 --verbose`,  add `seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444"` in protractor  conf file, comment  `// directConnect: true`, run script.

Comment: Hi yong , I'm sorry to mislead you, I add a gif to present the process, I have not used the port 4444, is it necessary to run it on port 4444?

Comment: I just want you try start chromdriver manually on port 4444, then run script on `http://localhost:4444` to see chrome can open success or not? port 4444 is optional,  if not specify port, chromedriver will run on defaul port: 9515

Comment: Did you use some tool like `Putty` to login remove env, then execute testing command?